# Mongoexport exported files?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I'm new with mongodb. I just used the command mongoexport as follows:

```
mongoexport -d databasename -c collectionname
```

operation completed within few minutes, (around 300k documents exported) however I see no files anywhere. I've checked the current folder (as I thought it's runnnig as mongodump) but it seems empty as well.

Did I need to specify a folder? Where are the exported files located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specify in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--out)

> If you do not specify a file name, the mongoexport writes data to standard output (e.g. stdout).

You need to specify a file to write the export to using the `--out` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows, add the mongoDB path to your environment variables and choose your directori, for example:
Open cmd as admin,

```
cd C:\Users\Test
```

After that run:

```
mongoexport -u admin -p password--host hostname:port -d databasename -c collection --authenticationDatabase admin -o test.csv
```

You will have your file in

```
C:\Users\Test
```